# printf format specifiers for Perl API types

Tags: perl, xs

Are there macros that provide the correct `printf` format specifiers for `IV`, `UV`, `STRLEN`, `Size_t` and `SSize_t`? None are listed in [perlapi](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html).

---

C provides macros for the format specifiers for the types provided by `stdint.h`, such as `uint32_t`.

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t i = ...;
printf("i = %" PRIu32 "\n", i);
```

Is there something similar to `PRIu32` for `IV`, `UV`, `STRLEN`, `Size_t` and `SSize_t`?

---

The [larger problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) is that I'm trying to suggest a fix for the following compilation warnings produced when installing Sort::Key on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
Key.xs: In function ‘_keysort’:
Key.xs:237:12: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘IV {aka long int}’ [-Wformat=]
      croak("unsupported sort type %d", type);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Key.xs: In function ‘_multikeysort’:
Key.xs:547:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘STRLEN {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
   croak("wrong number of results returned "
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Key.xs:547:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘IV {aka long int}’ [-Wformat=]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For `UV`, the following macros exist:

  - `UVuf` (decimal)
  - `UVof` (octal)
  - `UVxf` (lc hex)
  - `UVXf` (uc hex)
- For `IV`, the following macro exists:

  - `IVdf` (decimal)
- For `NV`, the following macros exist:

  - `NVef` ("`%e`-ish")
  - `NVff` ("`%f`-ish")
  - `NVgf` ("`%g`-ish")
- For `Size_t` and `STRLEN`, use the builtin `z` length modifier.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - `%zu` (decimal)
  - `%zo` (octal)
  - `%zx` (lc hex)
  - `%zX` (uc hex)
- For `SSize_t`, use the builtin `z` length modifier.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - `%zd` (decimal)

For example,

```c
IV iv      = ...;
STRLEN len = ...;

croak("iv=%" IVdf " len=%zu", iv, len);
```

---

1. While `Size_t` and `SSize_t` are configurable, they're never different from `size_t` and `ssize_t` in practice, and `STRLEN` is a typedef for `Size_t`.

Answer (score 3):

If `Size_t` is the same as `size_t`, then `%zu` is correct.

`STRLEN` is likely, but not certain, to be the same as `size_t`.

If `SSize_t` is the same as `ssize_t`, then `%zd` is *probably* correct (it's complicated).

For other types, if you don't know what predefined type they correspond to, convert to a known type. Knowing the signedness helps. For example:

```
some_unknown_signed_integer_type n = 42;
some_unknown_unsigned_integer_type x = 128;
printf("n = %jd\n", (intmax_t)n);
printf("x = %ju\n", (uintmax_t)x);
```

`intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are defined in `<stdint.h>`.

You can get away with converting to `long` or `unsigned long` and using `%ld` or `%lu`, for example, if you happen to know that the type is no wider than `long` or `unsigned long`.

Comment: I was pretty sure Perl does provide appropriate macros, and I have located them. See my answer.